# More Vimeo videos in a single player that autoplays

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, vimeo

I am trying to add more Vimeo videos in a single player, that would autoplay, and will play the videos one after another, and repeat the playlist eventually.

I have found this http://luwes.co/labs/vimeo-wrap/ , it does everything I need, but it does not work properly, not even on their website, it plays just the first video.
BUT it works properly on their example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/luwes/uPgMv/

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://luwes.co/vimeowrap.js/vimeowrap.js"></script>
<script>
    vimeowrap('player').setup({        
        urls: [
            'https://vimeo.com/20768621',
            'https://vimeo.com/21953913',
            'https://vimeo.com/24581859'
        ],
        repeat: 'list'            
    });
</script>
```

Using Chrome browser, I see this error in the console:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://player.vimeo.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "http://luwes.co". Protocols, domains, and ports
>   must match.

Or maybe you know a better jquery plugin that would do the same thing? or maybe a WordPress plugin that can do that? I haven't found nothing better than the jquery plugin above.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but no, I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the vimeo forums, this is a bug on their end -

http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:104878

Unfortunately, the solution seems to be to wait for the new player to be released. As of one month ago, Vimeo staff said they were in the 'testing' phase.